# When to use permissions WRITE_CONTACT and READ_CONTACT?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

So here with my application, by clicking a button I open the application phone (which lets call ...).

My question is: should I put the WRITE / READ_CONTACTS permissions in my manifest while my application uses them only via another applications?

Comment: What do you mean "while my application uses them only via another applications?"

Comment: You should put the permissions

Comment: do you want save contacts from your app??

Comment: No, I just want to call a contact but not with my application but using the phone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add permission in your application as you are just launching another(**call**) application via intent.

Android require these permission when you are doing something related to it in your application. Otherwise there is no use.

Comment: Well, I will do like that! Thank you and I would tell you what google thinks =)

Answer (score 1):

There might be situations in which you might need to load all the User Contacts in your own app. In that case, you would need the READ_CONTACTS permission. As an example, any of the Calling and Contacts Applications would be using the READ_CONTACTS permission.

On the other hand, if you wish to be able to add new contacts to the user database, you would use the WRITE_CONTACTS permission.

To open a different application to make calls, you don't need any permission. Just launch an Implicit intent for the calling apps.